# ImportError when importing QgsRasterCalculator in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator, qgis.core

I'm running QGIS 3.28.8 on Windows 10, Python 3.9.5.

In the Python interpreter when I run

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterCalculator
```

I receive the following error:

> ```
> ImportError: cannot import name 'QgsRasterCalculator' from 'qgis.core'
> ```

Has QgsRasterCalculator moved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QgsRasterCalculator` class is part of the `analysis` module:

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/analysis/QgsRasterCalculator.html